# How to declare a global QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to have a class, which extends QWidget, that I can access in my whole program. I've already tried to declare it in the main.cpp (but this is obsiously not declared in the other files) or to to it after the class declaration (in this case, if I include the file more than once, I get the error `multiple declaration`).

Is it possible to the Widget as global, and if yes, how ?

Edit :

What I want to do is to write informations on an second window, which is an instance of the class Console (I have written that class).

Then, I have the class MainWindow, with the classes it contains; calculation_widget, and variable_widget, which contain respectively a list of calculations and variables.

I want to be able to write on the Console window from all those classes.

Comment: I say you can do this the same way you declare a global in `c++` but you probably should not.

Comment: I know this is not recommended to use global variables, but I want to access to write text on this widget from everywhere in the code

Comment: ***but I want to access to write text on this widget from everywhere in the code*** The `Qt` way to do that likely using signals and slots.

Comment: I had not think to that, thanks

Comment: We could give you better advice if you could better describe your code or give a [mcve]

Comment: If I understood well, I have to instantiate the class Console (which is the one I want to access) in MainWindow. Then, using slots and signals, I just have to take the text I want to write back up in MainWindow and then use Console's functions to write it ?

Comment: Yes instantiate the class Console in your MainWindow. In your console class add an output( QString ) slot. connect that to a signal in your other classes. Emit this signal in the other classes when you want to send output to the console class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using this, but it would be better than a global pointer. In case you need your window(-s) only once in your application you could use the Singleton (Anti-)pattern.

This is the SingletonTemplate class.

```
#ifndef __CSingletonTemplate_H__
#define __CSingletonTemplate_H__

template <class T> class CSingletonTemplate
{                                                                         
public:
  static T* GetInstance()
  {
    if (m_Instance == 0)
    {
      m_Instance = new T();
    }
    return m_Instance;
  }

  static T& GetRefInstance()
  {
    if (m_Instance == 0)
    {
      m_Instance = new T();
    }
    return *m_Instance;
  }

  static void Release()
  {
    if (m_Instance != 0)
    {
      delete m_Instance;
      m_Instance = 0;
    }
  }

protected:
  CSingletonTemplate() { ; };                                       // Hidden constructor
  CSingletonTemplate(CSingletonTemplate const&) { ; };              // Hidden copy constructor
  CSingletonTemplate& operator=(CSingletonTemplate const&) { ; };   // Hidden assign operation
  ~CSingletonTemplate() { ; };                                      // Hidden destructor

private:
  static T* m_Instance;
};

template <class T>  T* CSingletonTemplate<T>::m_Instance = 0;                              

#endif // __CSingletonTemplate_H__
```

You use it by declaring a class like follows:

```
class MyWindow : public CSingletonTemplate<MyWindow>
{
  friend class CSingletonTemplate<MyWindow>;

private:
  MyWindow();
  virtual ~MyWindow();
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(MyWindow);
};
```

And you can use this class my calling MyWindow::GetInstance()->...

For more information about the Singleton Pattern visit: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton